# How to extract byte located at index position defined in AL

Tags: assembly, x86-64, avx, avx2

Problem statement : need to extract from `ymm0` register the byte located at a position whose value is in register `AL`.

My method : (rather ugly) :

```
        ; Set XMM1 to be a "shift one byte by right" mask
        ; XMM1 : 000F0E0D0C0B0A090807060504030201

        cmp al,15   ; check if in lower xmmword of ymm0 or higher
        ja  is_in_higher
        xor CX,CX
        mov CL,AL
    loop_for_next :
       vpextrb edx,ymm0,ymm0,0
       vpshufb xmm0,xmm0,xmm1  ; right shifts xmm0 as mask
       loop loop_for_next
    ..
    is_in_higher :
        vperm2i128 ymm0,ymm0,ymm0,01 ; swaps upper 128 to lower 128
    jmp loop_for_next
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this ? Any advice is appreciated. The crux of the challenge is that the `VPEXTRB` takes only immediate index value, not a `CL` (or `AL`) register as index value

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code requires AVX2 (`vperm2i128`) and I was not able to test it, as I have only AVX. Anyway your code uses a loop for a task for which a loop is not needed. My solution uses a simple lookup-table and `vpshufb` (requires SSSE3) instruction for reordering the bytes. Tested in YASM.

Here's the code:

```
[bits 64]

section .text
global _start

_start:

set_example_values:
        mov     al,0x1e                  ; byte index: 0...31, 0x00...0x1f
        vmovaps ymm0,[example_data]      ; define the data

code_starts_here:
        cmp     al,15
        jna     no_need_to_reorder_octalwords

        vperm2f128 ymm0,ymm0,ymm0,0x81   ; reorder ymm0. zero top 16 bytes.

no_need_to_reorder_octalwords:
        and     eax,15
        shl     eax,4
        vmovaps xmm1,[rax+shuffle_table] ; each byte is an index, f0 = set to 0.
        vpshufb xmm0,xmm1                ; copy the right byte to byte 0 of xmm0.
                                         ; zero the rest bytes of xmm0.

        movq    rdx,xmm0                 ; copy to rdx.

        ...

.data
align 32
;                  f e d c b a 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
example_data do 0xafaeadacabaaa9a8a7a6a5a4a3a2a1a0
;                 1f1e1d1c1b1a19181716151413121110
             do 0xbfbebdbcbbbab9b8b7b6b5b4b3b2b1b0

shuffle_table   dd 0xf0f0f000, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
                dd 0xf0f0f001, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
                dd 0xf0f0f002, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
                dd 0xf0f0f003, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
                dd 0xf0f0f004, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
                dd 0xf0f0f005, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
                dd 0xf0f0f006, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
                dd 0xf0f0f007, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
                dd 0xf0f0f008, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
                dd 0xf0f0f009, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
                dd 0xf0f0f00a, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
                dd 0xf0f0f00b, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
                dd 0xf0f0f00c, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
                dd 0xf0f0f00d, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
                dd 0xf0f0f00e, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
                dd 0xf0f0f00f, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xf0f0f0f0
```

Comment: Thanks @nrz ... Essentially, you converted the loop search into a lookup read.. appears to be great for speed but will not the benefits of speed gain be lost by spending time writing out the "lookup table" to memory ? More so for a ymm register my lookuptable is going to be very large...

Comment: @user1104214 The size of the look-up table is only 256 bytes, so it fits in the cache. It's a lot faster than looping. My code works for `ymm` registers too, `vperm2f128` is used to reorder `ymm0`. If you target AVX2, you can get rid of `cmp`, `jna` and `vperm2f128` by converting the code to do `vpshufb` for `ymm` registers directly. You need to modify `and`, `shl`, the 2nd `vmovaps` and `vpshufb`. The size of the lookup table will still be only 1024 bytes, no problem at all. https://intel.activeevents.com/sf13/connect/fileDownload/session/B60A46A270EA953D00393C7628A4A665/FSF13_ARCS002_100.pdf

Comment: @user1104214 If my answer is helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the "V" symbol on the left side of my answer, so that it turns green. You may also upvote my answer if you wish, by clicking on the up arrow next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure but probably something like that :

```
and         eax,  0x0000001F    // eax  = [al & 31, 0, 0, 0] 
or          eax,  0x80808000    // eax  = [al & 31, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80]
vmovd       xmm1, eax           // ymm1 = [eax, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
vpshufb     ymm0, ymm0, ymm1    // ... 
vmovd       eax,  xmm0          // eax  = [ymm0.byte[al & 31], 0, 0, 0]
```

Byte extracted from ymm0 at location al is stored in eax.